# touchstart vs touchbegin events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, touch

What is the right choice for targeting the touch events on mobile devices?

There's no a single word about `touchbegin` at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Touch_events, while I've seen many plugins that use `touchbegin` event instead of `touchstart`.

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### touchstart:

When a touchstart event occurs, indicating that a new touch on the surface has occurred.

---

This is (touchstart, touchend, etc.) are available at the front end and you can control it via javascript/jQuery.

---

#### touchbegin:

Where i got it is an event in the `objective-c` and you can't track/controll it on frontend.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `touchbegin` event native in JavaScript. If plugins are using `touchbegin` they must be defining it themselves.

`touchstart` on the other hand is native to JavaScript, and if you're wanting to track touch events this is what you'd use.